# Object Changes Shape when added in blender game engine

Tags: game-engine, objects, physics

this is my first time using blender game engine for a game.

Im trying to make a game where a ball flies out of a camera when space bar is pressed, but when I fire the ball it changes its shape to an oval.

I changed the object to a cube but it turns into a rectangle[image]
The thing stuck in the ground in the background is the deformed ball

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure the emitting object and all of it's parents have a scaling of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0).

Comment: You are welcome. - please mark as resolved